# On the problem of determining coefficients in the feynman integral technique

Tags: calculus

Firstly, we consider this problem
$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{arctan(asin(x))}{sin(x)}dx$

In general, after implementing the above technique, we get:
$I(a) = \frac{\pi \ln(a+\sqrt{a^2+1})}{2}+C$

I've seen quite a few people use $I(0)=0$ and then use Newton to derive $I(a)$. But it's clear that that's only true when $I(a)$ is continuous at $0$. How do we get that? I have tried quite a lot but have no idea what to do?
I think this will be the case if the integral is indeterminate with all parameters $a$ or is an improper integral.

Comment: $\arctan(x) \le x$ given $x>0$, so in particular $\arctan(a \sin(x)) \le a \sin(x)$ given $x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. Hence, $0 \le I(a) \le \frac{\pi \cdot a}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!